# Publish webservice using Spring framework at Java SE project

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I am able to publish webservices using Endpoint.publish() method. besides I have used spring framework in many Java EE project and Java SE project.

Does spring provide a way of publishing webservice at Java SE project?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html

Comment: in this link server-side support is mentioned.I want to know how to publish webservice in standalone java project with Sprng-WS support.